# json exportar a shapefile python

Tags: python, json

Formulada una consulta y teniendo el resultado en formato json con 3 campos (longitud, latitud, Deportista) estoy intentando exportar ese resultado a un archivo shapefile.

Me estoy ayudando de estos post y los adapto a mi caso y me sale el siguiente error:

File "E:\Formacion\Formacion_Universitaria\Master en Big Data y Data Science\VIU\Temario\01MBIG_SISTEMAS Y TECNOLOGÍAS PARA LA GESTIÓN DE LA INFORMACIÓN EN ENTORNOS BIG DATA\Actividades\Actividad_2\datos\Python__Act2_JVF\Actividad_2_JVF_Plus.py", line 151, in 
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)

File "C:\Users\ORDENADOR\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 1351, in **init**
raise Exception('The target filepath {} must be of type str/unicode, not {}.'.format(repr(target), type(target)) )

Exception: The target filepath 1 must be of type str/unicode, not <class 'int'>.

https://paulcrickard.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/creating-a-shapefile-from-a-mongodb-using-python/https://paulcrickard.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/creating-a-shapefile-from-a-mongodb-using-python/

[image: error]

He probado a cambiar las comillas simples a comillas dobles pero tampoco. También me da error al asignarle la proyección. Pero paso a paso, primero el archivo shp y después la proyección.

Adjunto el fragmento de código:

```
mi_coleccion = 'tweets'
# db[mi_coleccion]
filtro = { 'geo': { '$exists': True, '$ne': None} } # tipo null de un documento BSON es equivalente al tipo None de Python. Valores booleanos de Javascript; equivalente en Python (true -> True).
proyeccion = { 
  'Deportista': 1,
  'Longitud_WGS84': { '$arrayElemAt':['$geo.coordinates', 1] },
  'Latitud_WGS84': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$geo.coordinates', 0] }
}

resultado = db[mi_coleccion].find(filtro, proyeccion)
type(resultado)

for doc in resultado:
    print(doc)
## ESE PRINT no muestra nada. Ignoro si hace bieen la consulta
##


## JSON a Shapefile
##
# from pymongo import Connection,GEO2D
# import shapefile

# db=Connection().geo
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
w.field('lat')
w.field('long')
w.field('Deportista', 'C', size=250)

for x in resultado.find():
    w.point(float(resultado['Longitud_WGS84'][x]['long']),float(resultado['Latitud_WGS84'][x]['lat']))
    w.record(resultado['Longitud_WGS84'][x]['long'],resultado['Latitud_WGS84'][x]['lat'],resultado['Deportista'][x]['Deportista'])
    
    x+=1         

# ## ERRROR ; Invalid sintax
# prj = open('Web.prj', 'w')
# epsg = 'GEOGCS['WGS 84','
# epsg += 'DATUM['WGS_1984','
# epsg += 'SPHEROID['WGS 84'',6378137,298.257223563]]''
# epsg += ',PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],'
# epsg += 'UNIT['degree',0.0174532925199433]]’
# prj.write(epsg)
# prj.close()

## ERRROR ; Invalid character in identifier....
# prj = open(“Web.prj”, “w”)
# epsg = ‘GEOGCS[“WGS 84”,’
# epsg += ‘DATUM[“WGS_1984”,’
# epsg += ‘SPHEROID[“WGS 84”,6378137,298.257223563]]’
# epsg += ‘,PRIMEM[“Greenwich”,0],’
# epsg += ‘UNIT[“degree”,0.0174532925199433]]’
# prj.write(epsg)
# prj.close()

w.save('mongoSHP')


# Otra forma:
# print ('Número de documentos en la colección ClubesNordicWalking :', client.get_database('MyBBDD').get_collection('ClubesNordicWalking').count())
```

Gracias,

Juanjo

Comment: No pegues imagenes; adjunta el mensaje de error como texto, legible ...

Comment: @CandidMoe he editado el post inicial y añadido el error en texto. 
¡Gracias!